# JPA : Count with predicate on MapJoin

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, predicate

I have a problem with a criteria count query with a MapJoin !
In fact it doesn't work !

Here is my code :

```
public long countItems(final String title, final String url) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<CmsItem> query = builder.createQuery(entityClass);
    Root<CmsItem> page = query.from(entityClass);
    query.select(page);
    MapJoin<Map<Lang, CmsItemLang>, Lang, CmsItemLang> mapJoin = page
            .joinMap("cmsItemLang");

    List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    Predicate titlePredicate, urlPredicate;
    if ((title != null) && (!(title.isEmpty()))) {
        titlePredicate = builder.like(
                builder.upper(mapJoin.value().<String> get("metaTitle")),
                "%" + title.toUpperCase() + "%");
        predicateList.add(titlePredicate);
    }
    if ((url != null) && (!(url.isEmpty()))) {
        urlPredicate = builder.like(
                builder.upper(mapJoin.value().<String> get("linkRewrite")),
                "%" + url.toUpperCase() + "%");
        predicateList.add(urlPredicate);
    }

    Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
    predicateList.toArray(predicates);
    query.where(predicates).distinct(true);

    CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    cq.select(builder.count(cq.from(entityClass)));
    entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    cq.where(predicates);
    Long count = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();

    return count;
}
```

and I have this error when I call the method url param or title param is not null :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: linkRewrite of: com.demkocompany.models.CmsItem [select count(*) from com.demkocompany.models.CmsItem as generatedAlias0 where upper(generatedAlias0.linkRewrite) like :param0]
```

Here is my entities :

```
public class CmsItem {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;


@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "cmsItemLangPK.item")
@MapKey(name = "cmsItemLangPK.lang")
private Map<Lang, CmsItemLang> cmsItemLang;



public CmsItem() {
}


public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public Map<Lang, CmsItemLang> getCmsItemLang() {
    return cmsItemLang;
}

public void setCmsItemLang(Map<Lang, CmsItemLang> cmsItemLang) {
    this.cmsItemLang = cmsItemLang;
}


}
```

and the second entity (for the Map)

```
public class CmsItemLang implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6832580916240288447L;

@EmbeddedId
private CmsItemLangPK cmsItemLangPK;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Lob
@Column(name = "text")
private String text;

@Column(name = "linkRewrite")
private String linkRewrite;

@Column(name = "meta_title", length = 128)
private String metaTitle;

@Column(name = "meta_keywords", length = 255)
private String metaKeywords;

@Column(name = "meta_description", length = 255)
private String metaDescription;

public CmsItemLang() {
}

public CmsItemLangPK getCmsItemLangPK() {
    return cmsItemLangPK;
}

public void setCmsItemLangPK(CmsItemLangPK cmsItemLangPK) {
    this.cmsItemLangPK = cmsItemLangPK;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getLinkRewrite() {
    return linkRewrite;
}

public void setLinkRewrite(String linkRewrite) {
    this.linkRewrite = linkRewrite;
}

public String getMetaTitle() {
    return metaTitle;
}

public void setMetaTitle(String meta_title) {
    this.metaTitle = meta_title;
}

public String getMetaKeywords() {
    return metaKeywords;
}

public void setMetaKeywords(String meta_keywords) {
    this.metaKeywords = meta_keywords;
}

public String getMetaDescription() {
    return metaDescription;
}

public void setMetaDescription(String meta_description) {
    this.metaDescription = meta_description;
}

}
```

I don't understand why I have this error when I try to do that ...
Because without the count (in an other method to find the items) it works well ...
But to count all the result of the search ...the request is false ...

Is someone can help me to correct this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

That error is likely due to the class com.demkocompany.models.CmsItem does not have linkRewrite property. Double check you do have it and the accessibility has to be public (I think)

```
  public String getLinkRewrite() {
    // ...
  }

  public void setLinkRewrite(String linkRewrite) {
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: I added the entities to help to understand the problem.

Comment: I added the entities because this method is not on CmsItem but on CmsItemLang , this is why I used a MapJoin, I added the entities to my first post, if you have and idea it will be very good ;)